# Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.annotation.plugin.ide.AnnotationBasedPluginModelBuilderService'

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, installation

After upgrading to the latest stable version of Android Studio i got this and it's impossible to start a project

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQhNw.png

Comment: Can you provide a little code snippet so we can dig a bit deeper into the problem?

Comment: Sorry it's my first post. I edited so you can see the code

Comment: i have same issue. my setup. i am on intellij and not android studio. i am connected to internet via proxy

Comment: @rakeshkashyap i solved the problem and you have to delete every file related to Android Studio and when you are installing it again appears a window to import the settings, you have to choose not to import settings.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix this issue by deleting the Gradle cache and restarting Android Studio:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not the best solution that i'm giving but it helped me to solve the problem and carry on...
so first, go to `gradle-wrapper.properties` and this should be your code:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

then go to `build.gradle(:app)` and this was my code when the problem was solved :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.infogram"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

remember, in dependencies part you can have another codes in addition, but just check the versions of common codes with my dependencies code to be same!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to update the distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper.properties file, just copy the version number and replace whatever you have

[official grdle website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html)

I had:
*distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip*

Now I have:
*distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip*

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovvmj.png)